# jQuery QueryBuilder : how to initialize it and set the read-only parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects, query-builder

I am using jQuery [QueryBuilder](https://querybuilder.js.org/) plugin. I initiated my queryBuilder then used [SQL Parser](https://querybuilder.js.org/plugins.html#import-export) to set a rule from SQL.

After, I want to set my queryBuilder to read-only which means the queryBuilder will be disabled. You won't be able to add other rules or change the current rule.

Based on documentation, it should be as [this](https://querybuilder.js.org/index.html#methods) but couldn't make it work.

```
$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRulesFromSQL', { flags: {
    filter_readonly: true,
    operator_readonly: true,
    value_readonly: true,
    no_delete: true },
  rules: ["name in ('Alex','Adam')"] });
```

Any suggestions please what am I doing wrong ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
    filters: [ 
     { id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'string',
    value_separator: ',',
    operators: ['in']
    }
    ]
 });   

// here I set the rule from sql query without ready only feature and it works fine
$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRulesFromSQL', "name in ('Alex','Adam')");

//Here I want to update the previous method to include read only feature. 
//There will be only that rule and you can't change it. 
//I couldn't make it work although I believe I did write the correct syntax

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRulesFromSQL',  { flags: {
    filter_readonly: true,
    operator_readonly: true,
    value_readonly: true,
    no_delete: true },
    rules: ["name in ('Alex','Adam')"]
    });




 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://querybuilder.js.org/node_modules/sql-parser-mistic/browser/sql-parser.min.js"></script>

<div id="queryBuilder"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the 2 snippets are different - the first has `flags` the second has `filters`. Also, the first has syntax problem - you should wrap the 2nd argument object with `{}`.

Comment: @MoshFeu the second snippets is working but without read only. I want to make adjustment on it to include read only. The first snippet is how i was trying according the documentation and the syntax how it should be but wasn't working for me. I checked different threads here and on github but didn't find similar issue to mine. that's why i posted 2 snippets. the second one works fine without ready only but when I update it to have read only feature it wasn't working for me. I did wrapped the 2nd argument as you mentioned but still not working

Comment: @DevTN Did you figure this out? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @barneyAgumble sorry I moved to a different job i don't have the source code to help you but I remember the filter_readonly: true didn't work for me but then i did a work around in jQuery to disable all inputs i was using in the filter and with css i grey out those inputs. I believe there are better solutions but at that time this came to my mind and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Flags at rule level works for me

[image]

https://querybuilder.js.org/#methods

[image]
Hopes that helps

Comment: thank you for your help but this i know. In my case i'm using setRulesFromSQL, basically the rule is just a text not an object as your example. I need to add the flags part where readonly is stated as on your picture. for example after i set the rule $('#Builder').queryBuilder('setRulesFromSQL', "Country IN('France')"); I want to add read only now so that users can't change it. Any idea please how to add the read only after setting the rule?